# com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am developing code from **http://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-tutorial**, no customization yet. I keep getting the error mentioned below. So, to avoid this error I added the following in `application.properties` file.

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.server.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0
```

The moment I added the above properties I dont get any error.

The error below for reference-

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1030) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:944) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:444) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:304) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:51) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:192) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$302e4429.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$302e4429$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$829e6899.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$302e4429.eurekaClient(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:359) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:176) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.getApplications(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration.peerAwareInstanceRegistry(EurekaServerConfiguration.java:158) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f259bc3a.CGLIB$peerAwareInstanceRegistry$4(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f259bc3a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c73a2430.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f259bc3a.peerAwareInstanceRegistry(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) [spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.javainuse.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
```

The moment I added those properties none of the instances will be getting

```
registered with ureka and I client is getting end up with the below erorr

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.javainuse.controllers.ConsumerControllerClient.getEmployee(ConsumerControllerClient.java:27)
    at com.javainuse.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.main(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java:22)
```

So my questions is, how we can avoid first error mentioned in this post ? Please guide.

Comment: No idea. Is eureka running? What is the rest of your configuration?

Comment: @spencergibb - Could you please follow the tutorial link & see if its works for you ?

Comment: i've got the same, eureka is running well, its just that none of the services can register:

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: @Gewure - How to fixed this issue now ?

Comment: hey @Sayali, im sorry, but i really can't remember. If you still don't have a solution, you could add some additional information to your original question, making it reproduceable in the same context.

Comment: Sorry this is a different issue, the reason your app works while you use "eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false" and "eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false" is that you are not registering nor fetching information from eureka. As soon as you remove them or set them true your client tries to connect and it is not finding or is not abel to connect to to your eureka server, check the property "eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone" is correct and that your Eureka server is answering, also check if your server needs authentication.

Comment: The only issue I see here is incorrect properties. The application.properties should have data like below:-

    `server.port=8761
    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=false`

In fact I used YAML and it worked fine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem might be you have not specified the correct port for Eureka server. If you don't specify the port it will try to use **default port 8080** which will lead to errors. Use configuration as mentioned below in your **application.properties** file. **8761** is default port for eureka server

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Also make sure your annotate you main class as below

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you state ***"Also make sure your annotate you main class as below"*** then also explain why this should be the case. Main part of your answer was given [here by user **veer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415528/8928024).

Comment: I had a few microservices, i wanted to register them to my `Eureka Server`, but none of them were getting registered. I was using `port:9000 `for my Eureka discovery server, then i changed the port to the default `port 8761` and it worked fine.

Comment: eureka.client.fetch-registry=false - adding this fixed similar issue for me. thanks

Answer (score 10):

Getting exception Connection refused . It means the server port number already running in background. Check your server port number running in background or not.

**Follow this process:**

May be running same port number in background, see and kill below commands in windows.
Go to command prompt->Run below commands ,

```
Find open running ports:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ano | findstr :Port number

Example: netstat -ano | findstr :8761

kill ports based on PID(process ID)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /PID PIDNumber /F 

Example: taskkill /PID 3740 /F
```

Kill all running services using above commands and set port number and write below code in **application.properties** file.

> server.port=8761

```
#set port number
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.server.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0
```

Just edit above lines. working fine.

Comment: @jeffCook, If you problem solved mark it . help this solution for others.

Comment: I had a few microservices, i wanted to register them to my `Eureka Server`, but none of them were getting registered. I was using `port:9000` for my `Eureka discovery server`, then i changed the port to the defalut one `8761` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Is EurekaServer running?

I had the same problem, the problem is I haven't running the Eureka Server.
After running the Eureka Server it started working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following configuration to the application.properties file

```
#Eureka's default port
server.port=8761
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, i have just solve it using setting.xml file, which should be reside into .m2 folder just below repository folder.
[setting.xml file in m2 reposotory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72AOx.png)

1) You have to just create this file in simple notepad, past below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <pluginGroups/>
 <proxies>
  <!-- Proxy for HTTP -->
  <proxy>
   <id>optional</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <username>proxyuser</username>
   <password>proxypass</password>
   <host>172.25.33.10</host>
   <port>8080</port>
   <nonProxyHosts>local.net</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>

  <!-- Proxy for HTTPS -->
  <proxy>
   <id>optional</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>https</protocol>
   <username>proxyuser</username>
   <password>proxypass</password>
   <host>172.25.33.10</host>
   <port>8080</port>
   <nonProxyHosts>local.net</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
 </proxies>

 <servers/>
 <mirrors/>
 <profiles/>
</settings>
```

than save this file as setting.xml

and put it into .m2 folder, below repository

2) Than go to your IDE (i have used ECLIPSE), windows->preference-user setting->brows file path to setting.xml (C:\Users\himanshun.m2\settings.xml) - >click update setting -> apply and close

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have configured property to lookup server where micro-services to be registered.

```
## eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761 // on which port server is running
```

So start eureka server first then it will get eureka server to registered

Answer (score 1):

For me proxy servers defined in my settings.xml were causing the issue .

In the settings.xml located in Windows C:/Users/[username]/.m2/ directory ,

Make sure to remove or comment out any dedicated `<servers>` , `<proxies>` , `<mirrors>` or `<profiles>` that might be causing connection problems .